# jQuery .data() and plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's .data() tool in a jQuery plugin but I'm getting some odd results.
Here is a cut down version of my plugin with the relevant code:

```
(function( $ ){ 

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) { 

            // Do some stuff
            this.data('name', 'New Component');
            return this;
        },
        getStateData : function () {
            // Function returns all data for save
            var state = new Object;

            state.name =  this.data('name');

            // snip ... Add some other bits to state
            // ...

            return state;               
        },
        setStateData: function (args) {
            var key     = args[0];
            var value   = args[1];

            // snip
            this.data(key, value);
        }
    };

    $.fn.component7Segment = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.designComponent' );
        }       
    };
})( jQuery );
```

If I call `$(instance-of-plugin).component7Segment('getStateData');` the plugin returns the correct 'name' however if I call `setStateData` to change the name it has not changed the 'name' value when I next call `getStateData`.

Doing `console.log(this);` in each function looks slightly different so I started trying:

```
$.data($('#object-id'), 'name', value);
```

This still doesn't have the desired effect.

Can anybody see what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're calling `setStateData` like this:

```
$(instance).component7Segment("setStateData", "name", "Foo");
```

the `setStateData` function should be changed to look like this:

```
setStateData: function () {
    var key     = arguments[0];
    var value   = arguments[1];

    // snip
    this.data(key, value);
}
```

Note the removal of the `args` parameter and the use of the special [`arguments` array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) instead.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/ShFHC/

Your original problem was most likely that you were calling `setStateData` with parameters `name` and `"foo"`. `args[0]` and `args[1]` was actually accessing the characters in `name` at that position instead of the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I was calling it via ("setStateData", ["name", "Foo"]) and console.log(key + ' ' + value) was showing the correct result. I swapped to your method but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Yeah... to say i'm confused is an understatement!

Comment: Interesting. If I call the function via the console it works correctly however if I can it from an event handler it doesn't...

Comment: Solved, the problem was how I was calling the setStateData function - brainfart!